# Enforcing the usage of a singleton via AOP or bytecode manipulation?

Tags: java, performance, parsing, xstream

I did not used in the past except via Spring or Hibernate , AOP or bytecode manipulation so I do not know exactly if they are appropriate for my current scenario.

I inherited an application that has very very poor performance because on each request is instantiating a XStream parser.

XStream parser is thread safe and if I would have access to this applications code i would have instantiated the parser once and reused it.

Is there a way to trick the application via some JVM setting anything that when it calls the constructor for XStream actually to reuse the same instance ?

Many thanks...

Comment: So you can't modify this code in any way?

Comment: Not allowed..already decompiled  and played al little but there are some constraints that do not allow me to do that :(

Comment: Does the code create `new XStream()` all over the place or does it do it in one place (like a factory)?

Comment: Both actually ..i saw as well some packges that have a static method getParser....but in other parts,i noticed just new Xstream...it is a huge app

Comment: Well in the former, you can do this trick I read about from Michael Feathers.  You create your own class w/ the same signature and package as the class with the `getParser` in it.  Load it first in your classpath but make your implementation reuse the same instance.  Yes it's a hack, but it should make those places faster.